# show that $A$ is orthogonal if and only if its column vectors are orthonormal

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant, orthogonality, orthonormal

can someone help me with this proof

Question :

$A$ is orthogonal if det $A^TA=1$.  show that $A$ is orthogonal if and only if the column vectors of $A$ are orthonormal?

thanks

Comment: The definition of orthogonal is $ A^T A = I$, not $\det A^T A = 1$.

Comment: Just to clarifty, $A$ is orthogonal only if its inverse is its transpose. So $A^TA=I=AA^T$, like Ihf said (I just want to make sure you understand that $(A^T)=A^{-1}$).

Answer (score 1):

Hint: take $AA^T$ and think to matrix multiplication